# Adding Sitemap file and route in laravel

Tags: php, xml, laravel, routes, sitemap

I have a sitemap.xml file in my view folder and this is the route:

```
Route::get('sitemap.xml',function() {
return response()->view('sitemap')
->header('Content-Type', 'xml');
});
```

But when i search mydomainname.com/sitemap.xml. It returns **InvalidArgumentException
View [sitemap] not found.**

I tried to search on google and youtube but not able to find any solution.

Comment: Just copy your sitemap.xml file to public folder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I moved sitemap.xml file to the public directory and the route would be:

```
Route::get("sitemap.xml" , function () {
return \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect::to('sitemap.xml');
 });
```

Now open the xml file through url: [www.domain.com/sitemap.xml](http://www.domain.com/sitemap.xml)

Answer (score 7):

Just move your sitemap.xml to public directory.
It doesn't need any Route.

Answer (score 1):

Just put your sitemap to public folder and hit the http://yourdomain.com/sitemap.xml

Answer (score 0):

1.Move sitemap.xml to folder view
2.Rename sitemap.xml to sitemap.php
3.Create route by code below:

```
Route::get('sitemap.xml',function() {
return response()->view('sitemap')->header('Content-Type', 'xml');});
```